# Trying to add a custom folder to assets path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

I'm trying to add a custome folder to the assets path:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("something....")
    # ....
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "my_folder1", "fonts")
```

I've restarted my app and when go directly to `http://localhost:3000/my_folder1/fonts/my_font1.ttf` or `http://localhost:3000/my_folder1/my_font1.ttf` in a browser, I get the `error 404`. Why? How to fix it? Note, 
it's in the folder "my_folder1" on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't how you access the asset pipeline. All of your URLs should begin with `/assets/`, and the path is the path to the file *minus* the leading subdirectory.

For example: `app/assets/javascripts/test.js` is accessed publicly at

```
http://example.com/assets/test.js
```

In your case, you should be looking at

```
http://example.com/assets/my_font1.ttf
```

Comment: what do you recommend for mobile assets? a separate folder  "my_rails_project/app/mobile_assets" with the same structure as the normal "assets" one?